# Read Quads into Jena Model

Tags: java, rdf, jena

I am using the following steps to read quads into Jena Model

```
InputStreamin = FileManager.get().open(fn); //fn--filename
Model md = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
md.read(in,null,"TTL");
```

Quads in file are:

```
@prefix dbpedia:    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> .
dbpedia:53b56e90c8a15fcd48eb5001 dbpedia:type dbpedia:willtest dbpedia:1 .
dbpedia:53b56e90c8a15fcd48eb5001 dbpedia:end dbpedia:1404394351023 dbpedia:1 .
dbpedia:53b56e90c8a15fcd48eb5001 dbpedia:room dbpedia:Room202cen dbpedia:1 .
dbpedia:53debf266ad34658725225ed dbpedia:reading dbpedia:0 dbpedia:2 .
dbpedia:53debf206ad34658725225e5 dbpedia:begining dbpedia:1407106678270 dbpedia:3 .
```

But on running I get following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.hp.hpl.jena.n3.turtle.TurtleParseException: Encountered " <DECIMAL> "1. "" at line 2, column 60.
Was expecting one of:
    ";" ...
    "," ...
    "." ...
```

Error is generated due to the Quad file only. A triple file is read clearly. Is there any other method to read quads into Jena Model?

**UPDATE#1**

I did as Christian has mentioned in the answer, but now I get the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.JenaException:
      org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1;
      Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

Same data file can be found at [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/llgratvkg21rf1a/energyevents15lineTime.nq?dl=0).

Comment: A "SAXParseException"  means you're trying to use a SAX parser, which means that Jena is trying to parse something as XML, which doesn't look like what you're trying to do, since the data is in some NQuads-like syntax (but not actually N-Quads, based on [AndyS's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32022552/read-quads-into-jena-model#comment51950857_32023822)).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are reading a Turtle File, and as of http://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/#abstract , Turtle is not compatible with N-Quads:

> This document defines a textual syntax for RDF called Turtle that
>   allows an RDF graph to be completely written in a compact and natural
>   text form, with abbreviations for common usage patterns and datatypes.
>
> Turtle provides levels of compatibility with the N-Triples [N-TRIPLES]
>   format as well as the triple pattern syntax of the SPARQL W3C
>   Recommendation.

What you are basically doing is, you tell the parser that it has to parse a "Triples-syntax" file but you pass down a "Quad-syntax" file.

Change your file ending to `.nq` and use `md.read(in,null);` instead. This should then automatically detect that it is "Quad-syntax". And of course also make sure that your file is according to the N-Quads syntax, as defined here: http://www.w3.org/TR/n-quads/

Comment: In addition to the correct answer, when Jena reads quads into a model, only the triples for the default graph are loaded (unless you setup the parser specially).

Comment: The data you show isn't a legal syntax I recognize.  It's not N-quads (has prefixes), nor TriG which use "graph { triples }". Graph names  should be URIs, not literals.

Comment: @AndyS, you are  right. I tried to add fourth value as dummy time. Now for checking purpose I presented same in URI format, but still with no luck.

Comment: See the answer.  It's still not Turtle format.  It's not N-Quads either (N-Quads does not have prefixes).